# Change active keyboard layout programmatically in Gnome3 on Arch

Tags: gnome, antergos

I'm writing some scripts to automate common things like changing the language/keyboard layout or installing legacy tools like browser, passwordsafe and so on. This is designed for an [Antergos](https://antergos.com/) installation, which itself is based on Arch Linux. My first task is changing the default keyboard layout. Although I selected German in the installation process, I got a English layout after installation.

Using the GUI, it's done like described here: http://mixeduperic.com/linux/how-to-enable-multiple-language-keyboard-layouts-in-gnome3.html

How can I set this layout programmatically? I'm looking for some kind of configuration file where I can replace the English one by German in some case.

Comment: Use `xprop -spy root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` then parse the output with your custom script.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Set_the_keyboard_layout

Answer (score 0):

In scripts I use

```
setxkbmap [language code]
```

to change the keyboard layout under xorg. To customize further,

```
xmodmap
```

can be useful too. Check also your locale configuration, see :

[Locale on arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale)